# Does Kafka Mirroring needs different zookeeper ensemble?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I understand that Kafka mirroring is replicating data across different data centers. I have some questions here as below -

1) Does these different data centers needs different zookeeper ensemble ?

2) Can these Kafka mirroring concept be a good option if we want to replicate data across 2 racks which are part of data center ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) If you have a separate kafka cluster in each data center, then yes, you should also have a separate zookeeper ensemble in each data center.

2) Replication between racks, in general, involves lower latency than replicating between data centers. You can consider mirroring between racks or running a kafka cluster / zookeeper ensemble that stretch across racks and letting kafka replication do the job (and possibly use rack-aware replica assignment [1]) depending on consistency, availability and network resiliency trade-offs for your use-case. In the case of 2 racks however, you wouldn't be able to retain a quorum and tolerance to either of the racks going down, so unless you can go for 3 racks, mirroring feels like a safer first choice.

[1] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-36+Rack+aware+replica+assignment